# Using continue statement within catch block in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can we use continue and break statements within try and catch blocks

eg.,

```
for(let i=0; i< arr.length; i++) {
  try {
     // Some condition
     continue; 
  }
  catch(e) {
    continue;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you should try first by yourself and reach out to people here in case you do not understand the working of your code.

Comment: did you get your hands dirty? if not please try running the code you have posted with some condition inside if block.

Comment: @RahulSharma I know it works but wanted to know if it best practice. Try catch enclosing callback is not a good practice, just wanted to know if that is the case with continue and break also.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### The answer is: Yes.

Example:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log(`Iteration ${i} start`);
  try {
    console.log(`Iteration ${i} try block`);
    if (i === 1) {
      throw new Error('error');
    } else if (i === 2) {
      continue;
    } else if (i === 3) {
      break;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`Iteration ${i} catch block`);
    continue;
  }
  console.log(`Iteration ${i} end`);
}
```

This prints:

```
Iteration 0 start
Iteration 0 try block
Iteration 0 end
Iteration 1 start
Iteration 1 try block
Iteration 1 catch block
Iteration 2 start
Iteration 2 try block
Iteration 3 start
Iteration 3 try block
```

An even better example:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log(`Iteration ${i} start`);
  try {
    console.log(`Iteration ${i} try block start`);
    if (i === 1) {
      throw new Error('error');
    } else if (i === 2) {
      throw new Error('continue');
    } else if (i === 3) {
      throw new Error('break');
    }
    console.log(`Iteration ${i} try block end`);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`Iteration ${i} catch block`);
    if (e.message === 'break') {
      console.log(`Iteration ${i} catch block: break`);
      break;
    } else if (e.message === 'continue') {
      console.log(`Iteration ${i} catch block: continue`);
      continue;
    }
    console.log(`Iteration ${i} catch block end`);
  }
  console.log(`Iteration ${i} end`);
}
```

Output:

```
Iteration 0 start
Iteration 0 try block start
Iteration 0 try block end
Iteration 0 end
Iteration 1 start
Iteration 1 try block start
Iteration 1 catch block
Iteration 1 catch block end
Iteration 1 end
Iteration 2 start
Iteration 2 try block start
Iteration 2 catch block
Iteration 2 catch block: continue
Iteration 3 start
Iteration 3 try block start
Iteration 3 catch block
Iteration 3 catch block: break
```

As you can see it all works as expected for both `break` and `continue` inside of `try` and `catch` blocks alike.

Comment: I just learned that if you use `console.error()` in your catch things will go wrong. Thanks for the answer, you gave me the conviction my `continue;`was ok and I should be looking at something else.